# How to do the tip method of failing bench without ending with a chest injury?

Tags: bench-press

Every time I do the method of tipping away the weights when I want to fail doing the bench press alone, it seems so I pull something on my chest. Could someone give me some tips on how to do this safely without injury? Or is this a risk with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to re-rack, if that's the tipping away method. This video sums up the best way to bail a bench press perfectly (if you're not doing a guillotine press):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeELa2ywm0M

1. keep the clips on the bar so the plates don't slide off
2. move the bar horizontally towards your legs and sit down

It's how I do it for years, never needed a spotter to save me.

The only other method I'd recommend for benching alone would be to use safety bars (if available).

Comment: I bench without collars and just dump plates. So much easier than rolling it down.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov there's always the risk of the bar flipping rapidly when you empty one side, then you might get hurt. Also when I fail, at the bottom, I usually don't have the strength to lift one side... And you have to load the bar again.